# I have an issue where I want to share value from a PCL project to platform specific project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

Hi I have just started with Xamarin.forms and
I am stuck with a problem where I have some pages in PCL project like login and dashboard, 
and I want to get set the shared preference values from code behind files of this pages like "Userinfo" in login button of Login page.
Please help me out,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need the [settings plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20160207110158/https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Settings) by James Montemagno.  Look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/281afe67-6bf2-416f-b0e8-0c8f285557c2/how-do-you-use-jamesmontemagnos-xamarinplugins-settings?forum=xamarinforms) how to use it.

You can use:

- Android: SharedPreferences
- iOS: NSUserDefaults
- Windows Phone: IsolatedStorageSettings
- Windows RT / UWP: ApplicationDataContainer